# Ajax Url didnt work in mobile browse but work in browser

Tags: ajax, iis, mobile, browser, codeigniter-3

"EDITED "Hy, i have simple ajax code for my login, it works well in my browser PC, but when i try it to my PDA zebra it didnt work, sometimes it works and i can login, but the javascript inside the dashboard(input) didnt run to(indrimuska editable-select), i didnt know whats the problem it is, this is my code for login:

```
$("#login").on('click', function() {
  $.ajax({

    url: '<?php echo base_url('login/login') ?>',
    type: 'POST',
    data: $('#quickForm').serialize(),
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(data) {
      if (data.status) {
        toastr.success('Login Berhasil!');
        var url = '<?php echo base_url('dashboard') ?>';
        window.location = url;
      } else if (data.error) {
        toastr.error(
          data.pesan
        );
      } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.inputerror.length; i++) {
          $('[name="' + data.inputerror[i] + '"]').addClass('is-invalid');
          $('[name="' + data.inputerror[i] + '"]').closest('.kosong').append('<span></span>');
          $('[name="' + data.inputerror[i] + '"]').next().next().text(data.error_string[i]).addClass('invalid-feedback');
        }
      }
    }
  });

});
```

and this is my code for editable-select:

```
$('#editable-select').editableSelect();
$('#editable-select2').editableSelect();
```

i got the error 404 not found
[image]

the url just work to 1 type browser, when i open it first in mobile browser, my web.config didnt active at pc browser and its same with my mobile browser when i open it first at my pc browser,  what should i do ? make separate for app for my mobile and pc browser or any suggest ?

Comment: i already change the login system url from using ajax to normal action and didnt use editable-select, so thats my web can work in mobile browse, but its  still make me curious why its that happen

Comment: Did you get any error messages when it didn't work?

Comment: i dont know how to check it at mobile browser, any suggest how i can check it ?

Comment: When you open the mobile browser, is there an error message on the page? or can't open?

Comment: no error message, i can see the login view like it should, but when i try to login, the button login didnt work like it should

Comment: i got the error message now, i their have trouble with my Ajax url, the url not direct to my controller and function, sometimes in mobile browser it works but at the sametime in my web browser it didnt work

Comment: I suggest you use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to view detailed error information.